# Android BroadcastReceiver makes app crash when app is not working

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a Radio application that uses a Service for media player and a BroadcastReceiver to check for incoming and outgoing calls to stop or restart the media player service, it works but when I quit my app the BroadcastReceiver is still checking for calls and it crashes my application even that is gone (it has been finish) here is the code

Manifest

```
<service android:name=".PlayerService" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"> 
            <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>    
    </service>
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallInterceptor">                     
        <intent-filter>                                                   
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/> 
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />  
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

the BroadcastReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class IncomingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {                                  

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                                         
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);  


    if (PlayerService.getInstance() != null) {
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {  
            PlayerService.getInstance().stopMusic();
    }
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)) { 
            PlayerService.getInstance().stopMusic();
    }
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)) {  
            PlayerService.getInstance().startMusic();
    }

    }else{}

}

}
```

How can I make it stop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the receiver from your manifest and register it locally in your service:

Use this code in your service's `onCreate()` method:

```
IncomingCallInterceptor interceptor;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //your code here

    incerceptor = new IncomingCallInterceptor();
    IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter();
    f.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    f.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
    registerReceiver(interceptor, f);
}
```

Don't forget to unregister the receiver in your service's `onDestroy` method:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(interceptor);
}
```

Comment: Just perfect this worked great! Thank you for sharing this piece of code! if someone else has a similar problem try this code out it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your broadcast receiver in manifest, thats why your app can still listen to those broadcasts even if you haven't launched your app (or run the service). To fix this, register your broadcast receiver programmatically inside your service so that it only works when the player is running and not all the times.

Or in your current receiver, before calling start/stop music methods, you should check if the service is already running or not.

Comment: But am I not doing that already when I do the if (PlayerService.getInstance() !=null)?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the crash log it will help more.
By reviewing your code, all is good, but when you check for  PlayerService.getInstance() not null
it will give you the instance always, just apply a mediaplayer object not null check as well, while your going to play or stop or pause.

Hope it will help you.